# how can i give access to web service just one time

Tags: web-services, security, ws-security

i have a web site app developped with larevel 4.2, in which i have some web service call with ajax.
My problem is that the url and the credentials of the web service are shown to the user. is there a method to give the user a credential that is vailable just one time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be bad form to use security credentials directly in an Ajax call.  IF you are using a web-security product, then it likely supports user sessions.  After a user has logged into the secured site, he/she is provided a special cookie that identifies both the person and the client machine being used.  Every web-security product provides back-end applications access to this user's credentials, usually via a key called SESSION_ID.  This, in combination with a secured SSL connection, can be used to verify both whom the user is and the machine they are connecting from.  The Ajax call shouldn't require anything beyond verification of this SESSION_ID.

I am worried here that you may be using an 'off-site' Ajax call.  As more and more browsers are disallowing cross-site scripting by default, that would be a really bad idea.  If this is the case, then a redesign of your web service should be performed, so that any required credentials are maintained securely on your server and not provided to the client.